# Filter array of strings, including "like" condition

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, string, filter

If my main array is `["Hello","Bye","Halo"]`, and I'm searching for `"lo"`, it will filter the array only to `["Hello", "Halo"]`.

This is what I've tried:

```
 let matchingTerms = filter(catalogNames) {
        $0.rangeOfString(self.txtField.text!, options: .CaseInsensitiveSearch) !=  nil
    }
```

It throws

```
Type of expression is ambiguous without more context
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 118, accepted):

Use `contains` instead:

```
let arr = ["Hello","Bye","Halo"]
let filtered = arr.filter { $0.contains("lo") }
print(filtered)
```

Output

> ["Hello", "Halo"]

Thanks to @user3441734 for pointing out that functionality is of course only available when you `import Foundation`

Comment: .. and don't forget import Foundation

Comment: @user3441734 thanks, you are right about that one - always forget the imports because they are already in the project.

Comment: how to add more than one condition in this ?
e.g. let filtered = arr.filter { $0.containsString("lo")  OR $0.containsString("ll") }
Will work this ?

Comment: you need to plug in `lowercased()` for better results

Answer (score 34):

> ***In Swift 3.0***

```
let terms = ["Hello","Bye","Halo"]

var filterdTerms = [String]()


func filterContentForSearchText(searchText: String) {
    filterdTerms = terms.filter { term in
        return term.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased())
    }
}


filterContentForSearchText(searchText: "Lo")
print(filterdTerms)
```

***Output***

```
["Hello", "Halo"]
```

Comment: He asked for swift **two** syntax. What is the point of providing a swift3 answer?

Comment: When some one search for filter string array only, he/she will get answer as well as may update knowledge of syntax in upgraded version

Comment: I think it was asked for Swift 2, cose of it was actual at that moment, now we working with Swift 3 so it's more valuable for this moment.

Comment: @GhostCat because people like me come from Google looking for Swift 3 solutions :)

Comment: this is giving me error in playground
Value of type 'String' ha no member 'contains'

Answer (score 10):

Swift 3.1

```
let catalogNames = [ "Hats", "Coats", "Trousers" ]
let searchCatalogName = "Hats"

let filteredCatalogNames = catalogNames.filter { catalogName in 
    return catalogName.localizedCaseInsensitiveContains(searchCatalogName)
}

print(filteredCatalogNames)
```

Answer (score 4):

my try...

```
let brands = ["Apple", "FB", "Google", "Microsoft", "Amazon"]

let b = brands.filter{(x) -> Bool in 
(x.lowercased().range(of: "A".lowercased()) != nil)
}
print(b) //["Apple", "Amazon"]
```

Answer (score 3):

with help of String extension you can use pure Swift solution (without import Foundation). I didn't check the speed, but it shouldn't be worse as the foundation equivalent.

```
extension String {
    func contains(string: String)->Bool {
        guard !self.isEmpty else {
            return false
        }
        var s = self.characters.map{ $0 }
        let c = string.characters.map{ $0 }
        repeat {
            if s.startsWith(c){
                return true
            } else {
                s.removeFirst()
            }
        } while s.count > c.count - 1
        return false
    }
}

let arr = ["Hello","Bye","Halo"]
let filtered = arr.filter { $0.contains("lo") }

print(filtered) // ["Hello", "Halo"]

"a".contains("alphabet") // false
"alphabet".contains("")  // true
```

Answer (score 2):

You also need to compare to NSNotFound. The documentation for rangeOfString:options: says:

> An NSRange structure giving the location and length in the receiver of the first occurrence of aString, modulo the options in mask. Returns {NSNotFound, 0} if aString is not found or is empty (@"").

```
import Foundation

let catalogNames = [ "Hats", "Coats", "Trousers" ]

let matchingTerms = catalogNames.filter {
  $0.rangeOfString(self.txtField.text!, options: .CaseInsensitiveSearch).location != NSNotFound
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 5**:
Considered below example. Filtering (case insensitive) out data from array 1 and populating 2nd array  with that

```
let data = ["Apple", "Oranges", "Banana", "Grapes"]
var filteredData = [String]()

func filterText(_ text: String?) {
    guard let text = text else {return}
    
    filteredData.removeAll()
    for element in data {
        if element.lowercased().starts(with: text.lowercased()){
            filteredData.append(element)
        }
    }
}
```