# NSPredicate filter array using all characters before delimiter

Tags: ios, swift, nspredicate

I am currently filtering using

```
self.searchArray.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)
let searchPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF CONTAINS[c] %@", searchController.searchBar.text!)
let array = (Array(exampleArray) as NSArray).filteredArrayUsingPredicate(searchPredicate)
self.searchArray = array as! [String]
```

It is filtering the whole string, However, I only want to filter using all characters that exist before my delimiter.  For example:

each array value has a delimiter which is   "$%^"

example array contains [abc$%^12], [efg$%^32], [tyh$%^77]

I only want the filtering to include on all characters before $%^ which would be abc, efg, and tyh

Comment: what you are saying is that the search for "2" should not yield any result, the search for "e" should yield "efg$%^32", etc.!? Does it have to be a predicate?

Comment: @luk2302 correct.  Only values before the delimiter should show up on my search results.  I'm trying to accomplish this using NSPredicate

Comment: Okay, then I cannot help you, predicates are just yeiks ^^

Answer (score 1):

You can do this without using `NSPredicate`. [Stub](http://swiftstub.com/257274877):

```
let searchBarText = "h"
let exampleArray = ["abc$%^12", "efg$%^32", "tyh$%^77"]

let searchResults = exampleArray.filter {
    let components = $0.componentsSeparatedByString("$%^")
    return components[0].containsString(searchBarText)
}
```

Comment: please, put import Foundation at the beginning, so it will be clear that 'String' has no member 'componentsSeparatedByString'. and check the result with wanted by OP

Comment: SwiftStub doesn't allow any `import` statement. The OP can add it to his real code

Comment: it gives me ["tyh$%^77"], so all elements containing "h". is that wanted by OP?

Comment: let searchResults = exampleArray.map { $0.componentsSeparatedByString("$%^")[0] }
    .filter { $0.containsString(searchBarText) }; print(searchResults) // ["tyh"]

Comment: what if I wanted to store the second part of that string?

Comment: @StopTonio not really sure what you want. Can you edit your question to include the expected output?

Answer (score 0):

'pure' Swift solution :-) (I don't like any help of Foundation)

```
let arr = ["abc$%^12", "efg$%^32", "tyh$%^77", "nodelemiter"]
let delimiter = "$%^"

func splitByDelimeter(let str: String, delimiter: String)->(String,String) {
    var str1 = ""
    var str2 = str
    while !str2.hasPrefix(delimiter) && str2.characters.count > 0 {
        str1.append(str2.removeAtIndex(str2.startIndex))
    }
    if (str1 == str) { return (str1, "") }
    let r = Range(start: str2.startIndex, end: str2.startIndex.advancedBy(delimiter.characters.count))
    str2.removeRange(r)
    return (str1, str2)
}

let res = arr.map { splitByDelimeter($0, delimiter: delimiter).0 }
print(res)  // ["abc", "efg", "tyh", "nodelemiter"]

let res2 = arr.map { splitByDelimeter($0, delimiter: delimiter) }
print(res2) // [("abc", "12"), ("efg", "32"), ("tyh", "77"), ("nodelemiter", "")]
```

it should work, even there is only delimiter, or more than one delimiter in your string. First occurrence of delimiter will split the string to two parts.

UPDATE

with help of String extension you can do it as ...

```
let arr = ["abc$%^12", "efg$%^32", "tyh$%^77", "nodelemiter", "$%^jhdk$%^jdhjahsd", "22lemar$%^fralemdo"]

extension String {

    func splitBy(delimiter: String)->(String,String) {
        var str1 = ""
        var str2 = self
        while !str2.hasPrefix(delimiter) && str2.characters.count > 0 {
            str1.append(str2.removeAtIndex(str2.startIndex))
        }
        if (str1 == self) { return (str1, "") }
        let r = Range(start: str2.startIndex, end: str2.startIndex.advancedBy(delimiter.characters.count))
        str2.removeRange(r)
        return (str1, str2)
    }

    func contains(string: String)->Bool {
        guard !self.isEmpty else {
            return false
        }
        var s = self.characters.map{ $0 }
        let c = string.characters.map{ $0 }
        repeat {
            if s.startsWith(c){
                return true
            } else {
                s.removeFirst()
            }
        } while s.count > c.count - 1
        return false
    }
}

let filtered = arr.map{ $0.splitBy("$%^").0 }.filter { $0.contains("lem") }
print(filtered) // ["nodelemiter", "22lemar"]
```

or you can use hasPrefix to narrow search by typing more chars to you search box ... etc.

```
let arr2 = ["abc$%^12", "abefg$%^32", "tyhab$%^77"]
let filtered2 = arr2.map{ $0.splitBy("$%^").0 }.filter { $0.hasPrefix("ab") }
print(filtered2) // ["abc", "abefg"]
```

Comment: this is what I wanted, however is there a way to do this using nspredicate?

Comment: because im using searchController.searchBar.text! as the input text and its filtering the array

Comment: do you like to filter the resulting res from my example? if yes, by which criteria? please specify the criteria and probably i can help you with 'pure' Swift solution :-)

Comment: try use this http://stackoverflow.com/a/34513623/3441734 to filter res from my example

Comment: getting an error on $0.splitBy :  type of expression is ambiguous without more context

Comment: copy and past to your playground. it works ... or publish the whole expression, where you experienced an error. do you know what is a tuple? resulting type of that function is tuple (String, String), check your usage