# How to filter the values of a string array in a struct object substring wise

Tags: struct, swift3, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller

I want to check a value is there in section object.This code is working fine but if I write the complete name only it will get in to the filtered object.i need to get the filtered data when the search test  matches with a substring in the string array

```
["A": ["Affenpoo", "Affenpug", "Affenshire", "Affenwich", "Afghan Collie", "Afghan Hound"], "B": ["Bagle Hound", "Boxer"]]

        struct Objects {
             var sectionName : String!
             var sectionObjects : [String] 
             var sectionid:[String]!
             var sectionph:[String]!
             var sectionImage:[String]!
                }

        var objectArray = [Objects]()
        var objectArrayFilter = [Objects]()

    objectArrayFilter = objectArray.filter({$0.sectionObjects.contains(searchBar.text!)})
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if array contains part of a string in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30828074/check-if-array-contains-part-of-a-string-in-swift)

Comment: Another one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34511918/swift-2-filter-array-of-strings-including-like-condition.

Comment: they use arrays' I used structure,so some confusion

Comment: `$0.sectionObjects` is the array, and you have to check if some string in that array contains the search text.

Comment: @SHINTOJOSEPH Accepted answer will return all object in inner array sectionObjects if you search for specific item, Or you want something like that if you enter in textfiled **afg** then it should return only two object **"Afghan Collie", "Afghan Hound"** with section A, I'm asking this because accepted answer will return all objects of in sectionObjects array.

Comment: @NiravD yea accepted answer is returning all the objects in section objects array.How to fix that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want filter like that if you enter string **`afg`** in `UITextField` then it should return only two object **"Afghan Collie", "Afghan Hound"** with section `A`, then you can make it like this.

```
objectArrayFilter = objectArray.flatMap {
    var filterObjects = $0
    filterObjects.sectionObjects = $0.sectionObjects.filter { 
        $0.range(of : searchBar.text!, options: .caseInsensitive) != nil
    }
    return filterObjects.sectionObjects.isEmpty ? nil : filterObjects
}
```

**Edit:** Struct that you have make is not proper what you need to do is make another struct and make with property object,id,ph and image all type of string and then make array of this struct inside your Object struct.

```
struct SubObjects {
    var sectionObject: String!
    var sectionid: String!
    var sectionph: String!
    var sectionImage: String!
}

struct Objects {
    var sectionName : String!
    var sectionObjects : [SubObjects]! 
}
```

Now filter this way.

```
var objectArray = [Objects]()
var objectArrayFilter = [Objects]()

objectArrayFilter = objectArray.flatMap {
    var filterObjects = $0
    filterObjects.sectionObjects = $0.sectionObjects.filter { 
        $0.sectionObject.range(of : searchBar.text!, options: .caseInsensitive) != nil
    }
    return filterObjects.sectionObjects.isEmpty ? nil : filterObjects
}
```

Comment: Welcome mate :)

Comment: at the time of searching name is  coming in the name field of session but all the id 's and images of the section is coming in filteredsection object

Comment: From where this Id and images come from there is nothing like that in your question

Comment: what if the struct objects contains section_id and sectionoimages

Comment: Struct that you have make is not proper what you need to do is make another struct and make with property object,id,ph and image all type of string and then make array of this struct inside your Object struct

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following :

```
objectArrayFilter = objectArray.filter { $0.sectionObjects.contains(where: { $0.contains(searchBar.text!) }) }
```