# What are the differences between throws and rethrows in Swift?

Tags: swift, error-handling, try-catch, throws, rethrow

After searching for some references to figure it out, -unfortunately- I could not find useful -and simple- description about understanding the differences between `throws` and `rethrows`. It is kind of confusing when try to understand how we should use them.

I would mention that I am kind of familiar with the -default- `throws` with its simplest form for propagating an error, as follows:

```
enum CustomError: Error {
    case potato
    case tomato
}

func throwCustomError(_ string: String) throws {
    if string.lowercased().trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces) == "potato" {
        throw CustomError.potato
    }

    if string.lowercased().trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces) == "tomato" {
        throw CustomError.tomato
    }
}

do {
    try throwCustomError("potato")
} catch let error as CustomError {
    switch error {
    case .potato:
        print("potatos catched") // potatos catched
    case .tomato:
        print("tomato catched")
    }
}
```

So far so good, but the problem arises when:

```
func throwCustomError(function:(String) throws -> ()) throws {
    try function("throws string")
}

func rethrowCustomError(function:(String) throws -> ()) rethrows {
    try function("rethrows string")
}

rethrowCustomError { string in
    print(string) // rethrows string
}

try throwCustomError { string in
    print(string) // throws string
}
```

what I know so far is when calling a function that `throws` it has to be handled by a `try`, unlike the `rethrows`. So what?! What is logic that we should follow when deciding to use `throws` or `rethrows`?

Answer (score 231, accepted):

From ["Declarations"](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Declarations.html) in the Swift book:

> **Rethrowing Functions and Methods**
>
> A function or method can be declared with the `rethrows` keyword to
> indicate that it throws an error only if one of its function
> parameters throws an error. These functions and methods are known as
> *rethrowing functions* and *rethrowing methods*. Rethrowing functions and
> methods must have at least one throwing function parameter.

A typical example is the [`map`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/3017522-map) method:

```
public func map<T>(_ transform: (Element) throws -> T) rethrows -> [T]
```

If `map` is called with a non-throwing transform, it does not throw
an error itself and can be called without `try`:

```
// Example 1:

let a = [1, 2, 3]

func f1(n: Int) -> Int {
    return n * n
}

let a1 = a.map(f1)
```

But if `map` is called with a throwing closure then itself can throw
and must be called with `try`:

```
// Example 2:

let a = [1, 2, 3]
enum CustomError: Error {
    case illegalArgument
}

func f2(n: Int) throws -> Int {
    guard n >= 0 else {
        throw CustomError.illegalArgument
    }
    return n*n
}


do {
    let a2 = try a.map(f2)
} catch {
    // ...
}
```

- If `map` were declared as `throws` instead of `rethrows` then you would
  have to call it with `try` even in example 1,
  which is "inconvenient" and bloats the code unnecessary.
- If `map` were declared without `throws/rethrows` then you could not
  call it with a throwing closure as in example 2.

The same is true for other methods from the Swift Standard Library
which take function parameters: `filter()`, `index(where:)`, `forEach()` and many many more.

In your case,

```
func throwCustomError(function:(String) throws -> ()) throws
```

denotes a function which can throw an error, even if called with
a non-throwing argument, whereas

```
func rethrowCustomError(function:(String) throws -> ()) rethrows
```

denotes a function which throws an error only if called with a
throwing argument.

Roughly speaking, `rethrows` is for functions which do not throw
errors "on their own", but only "forward" errors from their function
parameters.

Comment: The last sentence is golden!

Comment: @Honey: The last sentence in the answer is how I would sum it up.

Comment: Yeah that seems better. Would it be correct to say `rethrow`s are only used with closures, other than that they aren't needed?

Comment: @Honey: I do not completely get what you mean. `rethrows` is only used with functions which take function parameters that might throw.

Comment: How syntax would be if it do both??  Would it be "rethrows throws" ??

Comment: @KautsyaKanu: Only `throws` .

Answer (score 20):

Just to add something along with Martin's answer. A non throwing function with the same signature as a throwing function is considered a `sub-type` of the throwing function. That is why rethrows can determine which one it is and only require `try` when the func param also throws, but still accepts the same function signature that doesn't throw. It's a convenient way to only have to use a do try block when the func param throws, but the other code in the function doesn't throw an error.