# How to declare a rethrowing function?

Tags: swift, rethrow

I implemented the following function -as an extension of array of booleans- which could throw a `CustomError` error:

```
enum CustomError: Error {
    case empty
    case doesNotContainTrue
}

extension Array where Element == Bool {
    func indexOfFirstTrue() throws -> Int {
        if isEmpty { throw CustomError.empty }

        guard let detectedIndex = index(of: true) else {
            throw CustomError.doesNotContainTrue
        }

        return detectedIndex
    }
}
```

which works as expected:

```
let myArray = [false, true, false, true]
try print(myArray.indexOfFirstTrue()) // 1
```

Next, I tried to declare a function as:

```
func handleResult(_ index: Int) throws {
    print(index * 2)
    // ...
}
```

which should take the result of `myArray.indexOfFirstTrue()` and do something with it (for simplicity, let's assume that it prints the value multiplied by 2):

```
try handleResult(myArray.indexOfFirstTrue()) // 2
```

What I want to do is to declare `handleResult` as *rethrowing function*:

> A function or method can be declared with the rethrows keyword to
>   indicate that it throws an error only if one of its function
>   parameters throws an error. These functions and methods are known as
>   rethrowing functions and rethrowing methods. Rethrowing functions and
>   methods must have at least one throwing function parameter.
>
> <sub>[The Swift Programming Language (Swift 4.1): Declarations - Rethrowing Functions and Methods.](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Declarations.html)</sub>

So I can call it with non-throwing formula, thus it will not throws an error:

```
handleResult(myArray.indexOfFirstTrue()) // 2
```

But I am stuck of what should I edit to let it be a rethrowing function, so I tried to declare it as:

```
func handleResult(_ index: Int) rethrows {
    print(index * 2)
}
```

and I got the error of:

> error: 'rethrows' function must take a throwing function argument

therefore, I also tried to declare it as:

```
func handleResult(_ index: (() throws ->  Int)) rethrows {
    print(index * 2)
}
```

and obviously got the error of:

> error: cannot convert value of type 'Int' to expected argument type
>   '() throws -> Int'

What should I do at this point?

Comment: Why should `handleResult` be rethrowing? As far as I can tell, you just want `indexOfFirstTrue` to throw. You would still call it as `try handleResult(myArray.indexOfFirstTrue())`.

Comment: Unrelated, but your logic to get the `detectedIndex` can be simplified to `guard let detectedIndex = index(of: true) else { throw CustomError.doesNotContainTrue }`.

Comment: Thanks for the note @Hamish :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember, the argument is of type `() -> Int`! So you need to *call* the function passed in to get the result! You also need `try` since the function can throw.

```
func handleResult(_ index: (() throws ->  Int)) rethrows {
    print(try index() * 2) // see the "()"?
}
```

Now you can use it like this:

```
let myArray = [true]
try handleResult(myArray.indexOfFirstTrue)
```

Comment: Thanks mate. based on your answer, I still have to call it with the `try` (`try handleResult(myArray.indexOfFirstTrue)`), which is what I am trying to avoid. So what should I do the be able to call is as `handleResult(myArray.indexOfFirstTrue)`?

Comment: @AhmadF Then you have to handle the error inside `handleResult`, and remove `rethrows`.

Comment: What you mentioned seems to be logical to me, However, I would like to know- then how the logic of `map` function works?! as mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43305215/5501940), `map` can take a non-throwing function, which is not allowed in my case, if we tried to: `func getValue() -> Int { return 2 }
handleResult(getValue())` it won't work. appreciate your kind patience 

Comment: @AhmadF You should pass `getValue` without the brackets: `handleResult(getValue)` Remember you are not calling the function! Also, you can write it like this `handleResult { 2 }`

Comment: omg! oh man I just did the same mistake... That's what I meant of: I want to call it without the `try` (`handleResult { 1 }`).