# Throw from a trailing closure in Swift

Tags: swift

I'm doing some networking and want to throw from the trailing closure according to the response.

As a result, I've found that I'm unable to do so with an "invalid conversion" error.

I've reduced the problem to a minimal example - no cliches allowed:

```
func innerClosure(a: String, completion: (String)->Void) {
    completion(a + ", World")
}

func iCanThrow(name: String, closure: (String,(String)->Void)->(Void) ) throws {
     closure(name, {response in
        print (response)
        if response == "Hello, World" {
            throw ClicheError.cliche
        }
    })

}

try iCanThrow(name: "Hello", closure: innerClosure)
```

Ad you can see I want to throw a `ClicheError` from within the trailing closure - but the specific error is `Invalid conversion from throwing function of type '(String) throws -> Void' to non-throwing function type '(String) -> Void'`

I've tried using various combinations of `throws` and `rethrows` but I simply can't get this to work - even if I get the inner closure to `throw`  I get the following:

```
enum ClicheError: Error {
    case cliche
    case latecliche
}

func innerClosure(a: String, completion: (String) throws ->Void) {
    try? completion(a + ", World")
}

func iCanThrow(name: String, closure: (String,(String) throws ->Void) throws ->(Void) ) throws {
     try closure(name, {response in
        print (response)
        if response == "Hello, World" {
            throw ClicheError.cliche
        }
    })

}

try iCanThrow(name: "Hello", closure: innerClosure)
```

Which compiles, throws but doesn't actually throw from `iCanThrow` - meaning I can't throw!

Comment: For network request you can also use the `Result` type, see for example https://stackoverflow.com/a/54597264/1187415.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
func innerClosure(a: String, completion: (String) throws ->Void) {
    try? completion(a + ", World")
}
```

does not throw an error because `try?` is an “optional try”: It returns an `Optional` which is `nil` in the case of an error. Here the return value is ignored, so that errors are ignored silently.

What you want is

```
func innerClosure(a: String, completion: (String) throws ->Void) rethrows {
    try completion(a + ", World")
}
```

which makes `innerClosure()` a throwing function only if called with a throwing parameter.

`func iCanThrow()` can also be marked as `rethrows` instead of `throws` because it does not throw an error “on its own.”
See also [What are the differences between throws and rethrows in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43305051/what-are-the-differences-between-throws-and-rethrows-in-swift).