# How to handle 'throws' in custom XCTAssert function?

Tags: swift, xctest, throw

I'm creating a [custom assertion](https://medium.com/@amlcurran/custom-assertions-in-swift-3b91b413665e) with accuracy. I copied Apple's `XCTAssertEqual` method signature:

```
public func XCTAssertEqual<T>(
  _ expression1: @autoclosure () throws -> T, 
  _ expression2: @autoclosure () throws -> T,
  accuracy: T,
  _ message: @autoclosure () -> String = "",
  file: StaticString = #filePath,
  line: UInt = #line) where T : FloatingPoint
```

I tried creating my own with a custom type, making sure to forward the file and line numbers:

```
  func XCTAssertEqualUser(
    _ expression1: @autoclosure () throws -> User,
    _ expression2: @autoclosure () throws -> User,
    accuracy: Double,
    _ message: @autoclosure () -> String = "",
    file: StaticString = #filePath,
    line: UInt = #line
  ) {
    let value1 = expression1() // ❌ Call can throw, but it is not marked with 'try' and the error is not handled
    let value2 = expression2() // ❌ Call can throw, but it is not marked with 'try' and the error is not handled

    XCTAssertEqual(value1.name, value2.name, message(), file: file, line: line)
    XCTAssertEqual(value1.age, value2.age, accuracy: accuracy, message(), file: file, line: line)
  }
```

However, I'm not sure on the proper way to call `expression1` and `expression2`.

If I try the following, I get `Call can throw, but it is not marked with 'try' and the error is not handled`:

```
let value1 = expression1()
```

If I try adding `try`, I get `Errors thrown from here are not handled`:

```
let value1 = try expression1()
```

Obviously I could add `try!` but it seems like it would crash ungracefully in the XCTestCase (e.g. immediate crash rather than having the individual test fail).

`try?` seems like it would hide the crash.

Another option is to inline the function calls (`test2`):

```
    XCTAssertEqual(try expression1().name, try expression2().name, message(), file: file, line: line)
    XCTAssertEqual(try expression1().age, try expression2().age, accuracy: accuracy, message(), file: file, line: line)
```

However, this means that the expression is called multiple times. If it is time consuming or not idempotent, this could cause issues when evaluated multiple times.

---

What's the proper way to call these throwing autoclosures when defining a custom XCTAssert?

---

**Update:** I [tried the `rethrows` method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63269395/35690), but it doesn't behave the same as `XCTAssertEqual`. Namely, it requires that I add `try` in front of my assertion method, whereas XCTAssert never has that requirement.

```
class MyTests: XCTestCase {
  func test1() {
    XCTAssertEqual(true, true)
    XCTAssertEqual(true, try exceptionMethod()) // Works as expected: XCTAssertEqual failed: threw error "Err()"
    XCTAssertThrowsError(try exceptionMethod())
    XCTAssertNoThrow(try exceptionMethod()) // Works as expected: XCTAssertNoThrow failed: threw error "Err()"
  }

  func test2() {
    XCTMyAssertEqualRethrows(true, true)
    //XCTMyAssertEqualRethrows(true, try exceptionMethod()) // ❌ Does not compile: Call can throw, but it is not marked with 'try' and the error is not handled
  }
}

func XCTMyAssertEqualRethrows(
  _ expression1: @autoclosure () throws -> Bool,
  _ expression2: @autoclosure () throws -> Bool,
  file: StaticString = #filePath,
  line: UInt = #line
) rethrows {
  let value1 = try expression1()
  let value2 = try expression2()

  XCTAssertEqual(value1, value2, file: file, line: line)
  XCTAssertThrowsError(value2, file: file, line: line)
  XCTAssertNoThrow(value2, file: file, line: line)
}

func exceptionMethod() throws -> Bool {
  struct Err: Error { }
  throw Err()
}
```

Notice how Apple's `XCTAssertEqual(true, try exceptionMethod())` compiles just fine, but how `XCTMyAssertEqualRethrows(true, try exceptionMethod())` does not compile.

The fact that it does not compile, along with the omission of `rethrows` in Apple's signature for `XCTAssertEqual`, leads me to believe that adding `rethrows` is not the proper solution for this.

---

**Update2:** One way to get it to function very similarly to Apple is to explicitly catch the exception. However, this seems heavy-handed and like there is probably a better alternative. To demonstrate this solution, as well as most of the other solutions mentioned, here is a self-contained code snippet:

```
class MyTests: XCTestCase {
  func test() {
    // Apple default. Notice how this compiles nicely with both non-throwing functions and throwing
    // functions. This is the ideally how any solution should behave.
    XCTAssertEqual(User().name, User().name)
    XCTAssertEqual(User().age, User().age, accuracy: 0.5)

    XCTAssertEqual(try User(raiseError: true).name, User().name) // XCTAssertEqual failed: threw error "Err()"
    XCTAssertEqual(try User(raiseError: true).age, User().age, accuracy: 0.5) // XCTAssertEqual failed: threw error "Err()"
  }

  func test2() {
    // This solution wraps Apple's assertions in a custom-defined method, and makes sure to forward
    // the file and line number. By adding `try` to each expression, it functions exactly as expected.
    //
    // The problem is that the expressions are evaluated multiple times. If they are not idempotent
    // or they are time-consuming, this could lead to problems.
    XCTAssertEqualUser2(User(), User(), accuracy: 0.5)
    XCTAssertEqualUser2(try User(raiseError: true), User(), accuracy: 0.5) // XCTAssertEqual failed: threw error "Err()"
  }

  func XCTAssertEqualUser2(
    _ expression1: @autoclosure () throws -> User,
    _ expression2: @autoclosure () throws -> User,
    accuracy: Double,
    _ message: @autoclosure () -> String = "",
    file: StaticString = #filePath,
    line: UInt = #line
  ) {
    XCTAssertEqual(try expression1().name, try expression2().name, message(), file: file, line: line)
    XCTAssertEqual(try expression1().age, try expression2().age, accuracy: accuracy, message(), file: file, line: line)
  }

  func test3() {
    // One way to fix the multiple evaluations, is to evaluate them once and marke the method as
    // rethrows.
    //
    // The problem is that this causes the second line to no longer compile.
    XCTAssertEqualUser3(User(), User(), accuracy: 0.5)
    //XCTAssertEqualUser3(try User(raiseError: true), User(), accuracy: 0.5) // ❌ Call can throw, but it is not marked with 'try' and the error is not handled
  }

  func XCTAssertEqualUser3(
    _ expression1: @autoclosure () throws -> User,
    _ expression2: @autoclosure () throws -> User,
    accuracy: Double,
    _ message: @autoclosure () -> String = "",
    file: StaticString = #filePath,
    line: UInt = #line
  ) rethrows {
    let value1 = try expression1()
    let value2 = try expression2()

    XCTAssertEqual(value1.name, value2.name, message(), file: file, line: line)
    XCTAssertEqual(value1.age, value2.age, accuracy: accuracy, message(), file: file, line: line)
  }

  func test4() {
    // By removing `rethrows` and explicitly catching the error, it compiles again.
    //
    // The problem is that this seems rather verbose. There is likely a better way to achieve a
    // similar result.
    XCTAssertEqualUser4(User(), User(), accuracy: 0.5)
    XCTAssertEqualUser4(try User(raiseError: true), User(), accuracy: 0.5) // failed - XCTAssertEqualUser4 failed: threw error "Err()"
  }

  func XCTAssertEqualUser4(
    _ expression1: @autoclosure () throws -> User,
    _ expression2: @autoclosure () throws -> User,
    accuracy: Double,
    _ message: @autoclosure () -> String = "",
    file: StaticString = #filePath,
    line: UInt = #line
  ) {
    let value1: User
    let value2: User

    do {
      value1 = try expression1()
      value2 = try expression2()
    } catch {
      XCTFail("XCTAssertEqualUser4 failed: threw error \"\(error)\"", file: file, line: line)
      return
    }

    XCTAssertEqual(value1.name, value2.name, message(), file: file, line: line)
    XCTAssertEqual(value1.age, value2.age, accuracy: accuracy, message(), file: file, line: line)
  }
}

struct User: Equatable {
  var name: String = ""
  var age: Double = 20
}

extension User {
  init(raiseError: Bool) throws {
    if raiseError {
      struct Err: Error {}
      throw Err()
    } else {
      self.init()
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to mark your function as `rethrows` and then call the throwing expressions with `try`.

`rethrows` tells the compiler that the function only ever throws error thrown by one of its throwing input arguments. It never throws errors on its own. For more on `rethrows`, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43305215/4667835) excellent answer.

```
public func XCTAssertEqual<T: FloatingPoint>(
    _ expression1: @autoclosure () throws -> T,
    _ expression2: @autoclosure () throws -> T,
    accuracy: T,
    _ message: @autoclosure () -> String = "",
    file: StaticString = #file,
    line: UInt = #line) rethrows {
    let value1 = try expression1()
    let value2 = try expression2()
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately, adding `rethrows` causes the assertion method to no longer compile as-is. Instead, you must add a `try` at the call-site of the assertion method itself. With Apple's `XCTAssertEqual`, I do not have such a restriction, leading me to believe there is a better option than `rethrows`. I updated the question with this info.

Answer (score 0):

Declare your helper as `throws`, then add the `try` to your expressions.

Then in your tests, call your helper with `try` and declare the tests as `throws`.