# Are there cases where firstIndex doesn't return an optional in Swift?

Tags: swift

I have a simple function to find a specific element by index in an array using `firstIndex` like this, where `Entry.id` is a `String`:

```
private func findUserEntry(inEntries entries: [Entry],
                           currentUserID: String?) -> Entry? {
    
    guard let currentUserID = currentUserID else { return nil }
     
    guard let index = entries.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == currentUserID }) else { return nil }

    return entries[index]
}
```

I was refactoring my code to try to accomplish the same thing in different ways, as a way to learn and practice. I thought this function would effectively do the same thing:

```
private func findUserEntry(inEntries entries: [Entry],
                           currentUserID: String?) -> Entry? {
    
    guard let currentUserID = currentUserID else { return nil }
    
    return entries
        .firstIndex { $0.id == currentUserID }
        .map { possibleIndex -> Entry? in
            
            guard let index = possibleIndex else { return nil }
            
            return entries[index]
        }
}
```

However, I'm running into an error: `Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'Array<Entry>.Index' (aka 'Int')`. So, somehow, the value of `possibleIndex` coming out of `.firstIndex` into `.map` is an `Int` instead of the `Int?` I expected, like it is in the original version above. Why is there a difference here?

Comment: Yes if you need an index of a CaseIterable enumeration it will never fail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look up the Array function firstIndex(where:) in Apple's docs you'll find this: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2994722-firstindex

The function is declared to return an Optional Integer:

```
func firstIndex(where predicate: (Element) throws -> Bool) rethrows -> Int?
```

So no, it will ALWAYS return an Optional.

However, you are using map, which in this case is a function on Optional:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/optional/1539476-map

The function Optional.map() is declared like this:

`func map<U>(_ transform: (Wrapped) throws -> U) rethrows -> U?`

If the `Optional` contains a value, it is **unwrapped** and passed to the closure of your `map` statement. If the `Optional` contains nil, the map function returns nil.

Thus in your code

```
private func findUserEntry(inEntries entries: [Entry],
                           currentUserID: String?) -> Entry? {
    
    guard let currentUserID = currentUserID else { return nil }
    
    return entries
        .firstIndex { $0.id == currentUserID }
        .map { possibleIndex in 
            //At this point the value in possibleIndex can't be nil, 
            //so there is no need for the guard statement.
            //guard let index = possibleIndex else { return nil }
            return entries[possibleIndex]
        }
}
```

There is no need for your guard statement. If firstIndex contains nil, the map statement returns nil. If firstIndex contains a value, the map statement passes the unwrapped value in firstIndex to the closure and returns the result of that closure.

Answer (score 3):

`Array<Int>.firstIndex` returns an optional `Array<Int>.Index`, which is an `Int?`.

So, [`.map(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/optional/1539476-map) that you're using is a method of `Optional<Int>` with the following signature:

```
func map<U>(_ transform: (Wrapped) throws -> U) rethrows -> U?
```

> Evaluates the given closure **when this Optional instance is not nil**, passing the unwrapped value as a parameter.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way I can evaluate in the closure of `map` or another function even when it is nil?

Comment: Why do you need to, though? You can just do `return entries.firstIndex {...}.map { entries[$0] }`, or just use `.first(where:)`

Comment: Thanks. I saw that in the documentation, but it is a confusing method signature to me because I didn’t understand the “throws” and “rethrows” syntax and couldn’t find a good explanation of it.

Comment: I was mostly focusing on the fact that the closured gets a `Wrapped` - i.e. the non-optional value. The `throws` & `rethrows` part isn't really related to your question, but if you want, you could read more about the differences [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43305051/what-are-the-differences-between-throws-and-rethrows-in-swift).

Answer (score 1):

Other people answered your question, but what you really want is `flatMap`.

```swift
currentUserID.flatMap { currentUserID in
  entries.first { $0.id == currentUserID }
}
```

Or, if `Entry.id` is not optional, then remove the flat-mapping.

Comment: Very nice and concise solution!