# remove NIL values and partcial match from array

Tags: ios, arrays, json, swift

I have an Array of JSON Data that I want to delete nil objects and I have one object with the word Connex in a long string that I want to delete. This value is in the $0.financialInstitution field.

I've tried using filter to find the items I want to delete. My JSON data is rendering correctly.

I've tried working with the solution on this post: [Check if array contains part of a string in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30828074/check-if-array-contains-part-of-a-string-in-swift)

- I get an error: Cannot convert the value of type '(String) -> Bool' to expected argument type '(RateDetail) -> Bool' when I change the array to use my JSON data.

  ```
   // to remove / surpress nil values 
      let nonNilElements = rateDetails.compactMap {$0}

   // this does not work


   //code form post noted above, updated with my search parameters 
  and array

      let itemsArray = rateDetails
      let searchToSearch = "Connex"

      let filteredStrings = itemsArray.filter({(item: String) -> Bool in

          let stringMatch = item.lowercased().range(of: searchToSearch.lowercased())
          return stringMatch != nil ? true : false
      })
      print(filteredStrings)


      if (filteredStrings as NSArray).count > 0
      {
          //Record found
      }
      else
      {
          //Record Not found
      }
  ```

Value in RateDetails

.RateDetail(financialInstitution: "Your Neighbourhood C.U.", variableRate: "0", sixMonths: "0", oneYear: "3.59", twoYear: "3.69", threeYear: "3.79", fourYear: "3.89", fiveYear: "3.99", date: "2019-07-01")

value to be deleted:

RatesJSON.RateDetail(financialInstitution: CANNEX on June 30, 2019 at 00:30:20 ET", variableRate: "0", sixMonths: "0", oneYear: "0", twoYear: "0", threeYear: "0", fourYear: "0", fiveYear: "0", date: "2019-07-01"),

Blank value to be deleted:

RatesJSON.RateDetail(financialInstitution: "", variableRate: "0", sixMonths: "0", oneYear: "0", twoYear: "0", threeYear: "0", fourYear: "0", fiveYear: "0", date: "2019-07-01")

- I want to delete array values that are blank
- delete the value connex that is part of a longer string stored in the financialInstitution field.

Comment: can you give an example of what you have in rateDetails ?

Comment: and can you give us some example of what exactly is the output? Like this, it will be easy for me to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Is itemsArray an array of RateDetails?

If so, your filter closure states that each item in the array is a String, which isn't true. It's a RateDetail.

So the correct closure looks like this:

```
itemsArray.filter({ (item: RateDetail) -> Bool in
...
})
```

Comment: just as an adding on this answer can be that in the filter function item.financialInstitution should be checked for an empty value and for "CANNEX"

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if I managed to understand you, but try something like this...

```
let resultArray = rateDetailArray.filter { rateDetail in
 return  !rateDetail.financialInstitution.isEmpty && !rateDetail.financialInstitution.lowercased().contains("Connex")
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I have this a try and the empty values have been removed, but CANNEX is still showing. I copied and pasted part of the string from ratesDetails to remove the risk of typing errors.