# Check if one element in array is contained in string

Tags: arrays, swift, string, contains

```
let preferredCountryCurrenciesSymbols = ["USD", "EUR", "GBP", "HKD", "JPY", "RUB", "AUD", "CAD"]
let currency = "USDT"
```

I need code which loop the array and search in the string for .contains

I've tried with this, but it's not finding it

[Check if array contains part of a string in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30828074/check-if-array-contains-part-of-a-string-in-swift)

So basically the function I need is `-> Bool` have it or don't have it.

Comment: What result do you want? Do you want the index in `preferredCountryCurrenciesSymbols` for the value found inside `currency`? Do you just want to know if any value in the array is found inside `currency`? Show what you actually tried and clearly explain what result you got versus what you want.

Comment: If any value in the array is found inside currency

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question you linked is the opposite of what you need.

You can find if any value in the array is contained within `currency`:

```
let preferredCountryCurrenciesSymbols = ["USD", "EUR", "GBP", "HKD", "JPY", "RUB", "AUD", "CAD"]
let currency = "USDT"
if preferredCountryCurrenciesSymbols.first(where: { currency.contains($0) }) != nil {
    print("found")
} else {
    print("not found")
}
```

Comment: You could use `contains(where:)` instead of  `first(where:) != nil`. P.S. the downvote wasn't mine and not sure why anyone used one.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
let found = preferredCountryCurrenciesSymbols.filter { currency.contains($0)}.count != 0 // can use isEmpty also
print(found)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var res = preferredCountryCurrenciesSymbols.contains { element in
                return element == currency
          }
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, including an explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. It will be helpful for future users as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use **`contains(where:)`** to get that working.

```
if preferredCountryCurrenciesSymbols.contains(where: { currency.contains($0) }) {
    print("currency found...")
} else {
    print("currency not found...")
}
```